# Include custom module block within phtml file?

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, phtml, class

I've created a custom module for a distributor search with a php class/block inside.

Module Structure:

```
- /Distributor Search
    - /Block
         - DistributorSearch.php
    - /etc
        - module.xml
    - /view
         - /frontend
              - /template
                  - distributor-search.phtml
    - registration.php
```

I've tried to reference the DistributorSearch block when adding my phtml to the page in my default.xml in my theme.

```
<block class="Autosmart\DistributorSearch\Block\DistributorSearch" name="distributor.search" template="Autosmart_DistributorSearch::distributor-search.phtml"></block>
```

I've also tried to keep the phtml file within my theme and include like:

```
 <block class="Autosmart\DistributorSearch\Block\DistributorSearch" name="distributor.search" template="Magento_Theme::html/distributor-search.phtml"></block>
```

However I keep getting 500 errors and struggling to get the phtml to show on the page using our module class/block.

I can get the phtml to show on the page by but then I cannot use our methods inside my class DistributorSearch.php?

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="distributor.search" template="Autosmart_DistributorSearch::distributor-search.phtml"></block>
```

Any help to get this working would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Block class content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Autosmart\DistributorSearch\Block;

/**
 * Local Distributor Search Header Block
 */
class DistributorSearch extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return "testx";
    }
}
```

distributor-search.phtml contents:

```
<?php 
echo $block->getStoreName();
?>
Test Content
```

Comment: is `registeration.php` a typo or the name of your file? Should be `registration.php`.

Comment: Sorry thats a typo in my question, the module has correct and is registered and enabled.

Comment: Can you show more insight in what kind of error the 500 error is? Usually you can see this in your servers' error log.

Comment: [Thu Jun 22 13:59:37 2017] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.13.fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)
[Thu Jun 22 13:59:37 2017] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.13.fcgi"

Comment: ^ Thats whats in my error log, just breaks when I reference the block class as Autosmart\DistributorSearch\Block\DistributorSearch

Comment: Seems like your script is taking 30+ seconds to load. Could be an infinite loop of some kind in your class. Can you share the code of your block class?

Comment: I've updated my question, just has simple test function.

Comment: Why is your block extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`? Shouldn't it extend `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` instead?

Comment: I'm going to be writing a function that would get me the store view names and language codes so thought I needed to extend that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that your block is extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` instead of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`.

A block should always be a child of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`, since it contains certain logic to render the HTML and handle layout updates.

I think you're getting the 500 error because your block class is not a Block.

Comment: Just to confirm, do all module blocks have to extent \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template? How would you extend other classes?

Comment: This gets the phtml to show on my page but unsure how would I use this function in my phtml? I've tried echo $block->getStoreName(); and echo $this->getStoreName(); but cant get the ''testx" to show? I only have this in my phtml file currently? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes and no. They all should extend `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` or a child of that. `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` only adds functionality to work with `.phtml` files. If you want to add functionality, create your own block that extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` (inheritance) and use dependency injection to add the functionality to the block that you want to use in your `.phtml` files (composition).

Comment: Please share your `.phtml` file in your question

Comment: `$block->getStoreName()` should return "testx" since `$block` is the reference to your block class. `$this` in a template is a reference to the template engine.

Comment: Strange. It should work. Is the string "Test Content" rendered? Have you tried flushing your cache? Is your module enabled?

Comment: Test content is rendered, just doesn't echo the getStoreName? Module is enabled and I've flushed the cache.

Comment: What does `echo get_class($block)` say? Are your still using `Autosmart\DistributorSearch\Block\DistributorSearch` in your `default.xml`? Or is it still set to `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. That would explain a lot.

Comment: I forgot to update my block  to class="Autosmart\DistributorSearch\Block\DistributorSearch" - adding this back in still gives me the server error, as if it cannot find our module block?

Comment: Thanks for your help Giel Berkers :) I've managed to get it sorted, change the public function to protected function and this stopped it from working...